# Spawn a bash outside emacs?

Tags: shell, bash

I am trying to spawn a shell outside emacs, not in a buffer.

I have tried `(start-process "firefox" nil "firefox")`, wich does start a firefox process outside emacs, but when i tried `(start-process "bash" nil "/bin/bash")` nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because bash it is not the GUI program. Start your terminal emulator instead like

```el
(start-process "xterm" nil (executable-find "xterm"))
```